# OpenCV cvWaitKey

Tags: c++, opencv

I encounter this problem while using `cvWaitKey` function

Code is as follows:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>

void main()
{
std::cout << "openCV version: " << CV_VERSION << std::endl;
cvWaitkey();
}
```

So the error I have is:

> Link2019: unresolved external symbol _cvwaitkey referenced in function _main
>   error Link 1120: 1 unresolved externals

I put the `cvWaitKey` so as for the screen to stay there before I press the key.

How can I solve this?

Comment: you're not `using namespace cv;` and also you're using the C style function. Use `cv::waitKey();`

Comment: I used your method, However, the screen did not stay there, but exited after running

Comment: that's because `waitKey` waits only if there is a window opened. So to make it work you need for example to add `cv::namedWindow("something");` before the `waitKey`. Or just use `getchar();` instead of `waitKey`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. it is resolved

Comment: @KeillЯandor answer is the correct one here. Glad it works now.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try to use the opencv namespacing and the C++ function:

```
cv::waitKey();
```

Comment: Since someone is down-voting this, i would appreciate to know why.

Comment: I downvoted because this doesn't solve the issue, as reported in the comments to the question.

Comment: Actually, It DOES solve the concise linking problem stated in the question.

Comment: but does not produce the behavior expected in the question.

Comment: It doesn't solve a linkage error. If the problem were the missing namespace the code wouldn't compile in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

This

> Link2019: unresolved external symbol _cvwaitkey referenced in function
>   _main error Link 1120: 1 unresolved externals

is a **linker** error, meaning that you forgot to include the required libraries (`-lopencv_highgui` in this particular case).

Other issues related to this question, as mentioned by @Miki and @GuillermoMP:

- You should use the C++ API (the `waitKey` method in the `cv` namespace).
- Both `cvWaitKey` and `cv::waitKey` require that you previously create a `namedWindow` to work. Notice you can always use `getchar` (as pointed out by @Miki) instead.

Comment: plus 1 for the linking issue

Comment: a mention to `getchar` or similar will make the answer complete